Weil restriction of cycles and norm algebra
This question is on a concrete descrption of weil restricton of an affine algebra.
Let L/K be a Galois extension. Since I only care about the quadratic case, we may assume that $\Gamma:=\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)=\{1,\sigma\}$. We denote the Weil restriction by $R_{L/K}$.
Now we let $A$ be an affine $L$-algebra and $A\cong \frac{L[x_{1},\cdots,x_{k}]}{(f_{1},\cdots,f_{l})}$. Following from :
Springer, T. A., Linear algebraic groups, Perspectives in mathematics, Anniv. Oberwolfach 1984, 455-495 (1984). ZBL0564.20024.
We have that $R_{L/K}(A)=R_{L/K}(L[x_{1},\cdots,x_{k}])/R_{L/K}(I)$. Notice that $R_{L/K}(L[x_{1},\cdots.x_{k}])=K[y_{1},y_{1}^{'}\cdots,y_{k},y_{k} ^{'}]$. I have the following questions:
(1) Is $R_{L/K}(I)=(N(f_{1}),\cdots,N(f_{l}))$, where $N:L[x_{1},\cdots,x_{k}]\to K[y_{1},\cdots,y_{k}^{'}]$ the norm map? (We let $x_{i}=y_{i}+\alpha \cdot y^{'}_{i}$ where $\alpha$ is the primitive element of the field extension and substitute into $f_{l}$.Finally, we take the $N(f_{l})$ to be $f_{l} \cdot^{\sigma}f_{l})$.
(2) If $I$ is prime of height $k$, can we ensure that $R(I)$ is also prime? and what is the height of $R(I)$?
(3)In general, we have that $R_{L/K}(A)_{L}\cong A\otimes ^{\sigma}A$. The Speiser's Lemma ensures that $R_{L/K}(A) \cong (A\otimes ^{\sigma}A)^{\Gamma}$, where the latter is the $\Gamma$-invariant. From this relation, can we describe the prime ideals of $R_{L/K}(A)$?
Thanks for any comments. Reference on such algebra will be appreciated!
